# KDB/Q: How to write a loop and append output table?

Tags: kdb

Disclaimer: I am very new to the Q language so please excuse my silly question.
I have a function that currently is taking on 2 parameters (date;sym).It runs fine for 1 sym and 1 day. however, I need to perform this on multiple syms and dates which will take forever.
How do I create a loop that run the function on every sym, and on every date?
In python, it is straighforward as :

```
for date in datelist:
    for sym in symlist:
        func(date,sym)
```

How can I do something similar to this in Q? and how can I dynamically change the output table names and append them to 1 single table?

Currently, I am using the following:

```
output: raze .[function] peach paralist
```

where paralist is a list of parameter pairs: ((2020.06.01;`ABC);(2020.06.01;`XYZ)) but imho this is nowhere near efficient.
What would be the best way to achieve this in Q?

Comment: Whats your usecase here? Do you need all the date sym files to be consumed elswhere? Are you using a hdb? I get the impression that is what you are trying to create

Answer (score 3):

I'll generalize everything, if you have a given function `foo` which will operate on an atom `dt` with a vector `s`

```
q)foo:{[dt;s] dt +\: s}
q)dt:10?10
q)s:100?10
q)dt
8 1 9 5 4 6 6 1 8 5
q)s
4 9 2 7 0 1 9 2 1 8 8 1 7 2 4 5 4 2 7 8 5 6 4 1 3 3 7 8 2 1 4 2 8 0 5 8 5 2 8..
q)foo[;s] each dt
12 17 10 15 8 9  17 10 9  16 16 9  15 10 12 13 12 10 15 16 13 14 12 9  11 11 ..
5  10 3  8  1 2  10 3  2  9  9  2  8  3  5  6  5  3  8  9  6  7  5  2  4  4  ..
13 18 11 16 9 10 18 11 10 17 17 10 16 11 13 14 13 11 16 17 14 15 13 10 12 12 ..
9  14 7  12 5 6  14 7  6  13 13 6  12 7  9  10 9  7  12 13 10 11 9  6  8  8  ..
```

The solution is to project the `symList` over the function in question, then use `each` (or `peach`) for the `date` variable.

If your function requires an atomic `date` and `sym`, then you can just create a new function to implement this

```
q)bar:{[x;y] foo[x;] each y};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datelist:`date$10?10
symlist:10?`IBM`MSFT`GOOG
function:{0N!(x;y)}

{.[function;x]} peach datelist cross symlist
```

cross will return all combinations of sym and date
Is this what you need?

Comment: Sorry no, I think this is what I am already doing. what I need is to run the function on 1 date-sym, and output to a table, then do it again for another date-sym and so on. the output table'name should be changed based on the date and sym. for example, output20191005ABC, output20191006ABC etc

Answer (score 0):

Try to use two "double" `'`

```
raze function'[datelist]'[symlist]
```

`peach` or `each` won't work here. They are not operators, but anonymous functions with two parameters: `each` is `k){x'y}`. That is why `function each list1 each list2` statement is invalid, but `function'[list1]'[list2]` works.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your response to another answer you are looking to save the results with unique names yes? Take a look at this solution using set to save and get to retrieve.

```
q)t:flip enlist each `colA`colB!(100;`name)
q)t
colA colB
---------
100  name
q)f:{[date;sym]tblName:`$string[date],string sym;tblName set update date:date,sym:sym from t}
q)newTbls:f'[.z.d+til 3;`AAA`BBB`CCC]
q)newTbls
`2020.09.02AAA`2020.09.03BBB`2020.09.04CCC
q)get each newTbls
+`colA`colB`date`sym!(,100;,`name;,2020.09.02;,`AAA)
+`colA`colB`date`sym!(,100;,`name;,2020.09.03;,`BBB)
+`colA`colB`date`sym!(,100;,`name;,2020.09.04;,`CCC)
q)get first newTbls
colA colB date       sym
------------------------
100  name 2020.09.02 AAA
```

Does this meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a stab in the dark, but why not create a hdb rather than all these variables output20191005ABC, output20191006ABC .. etc and given you want to append them to 1 table.

Below I have outlined how to create a date partitioned hdb called `outputHDB` which has one table `outputTbl`. I created the hdb by running a function by date and sym and then upserting those rows to disk.

```
C:\Users\Matthew Moore>mkdir outputHDB
C:\Users\Matthew Moore>cd outputHDB
// can change the outputHDB as desired
// start q

h:hopen `::6789; // as a demo I connected to another hdb process and extracted some data per sym / date over IPC
hdbLoc:hsym `$"C:/Users/Matthew Moore/outputHDB";

{[d;sl]
    
    {[d;s]

        //output:yourFunc[date;sym];

        // my func as a demo, I'm grabbing rows where price = max price by date and by sym from another hdb using the handle h
        output:{[d;s]
            h({[d;s] select from trades where date = d, sym = s, price = max price};d;s)    
        }[d;s];
        
        // HDB Part
        path:` sv (hdbLoc;`$string d;`outputTbl;`);
        // change `outputTbl to desired table name
        // dynamically creates the save location and then upserts one syms data directly to disk
        // e.g. `:C:/Users/Matthew Moore/outputHDB/2014.04.21/outputTbl/
        // extra / at the end saves the table as splayed i.e. each column is it's own file within the outputTbl directory
        
        path upsert .Q.en[`:.;output];
        // .Q.en enumerates syms in a table which is required when saving a table splayed

    }[d;] each sl;

    // applies the parted attribute to the sym column on disk, this speeds up querying for on disk data
    @[` sv (hdbLoc;`$string d;`outputTbl;`);`sym;`p#];
    
}[;`AAPL`CSCO`DELL`GOOG`IBM`MSFT`NOK`ORCL`YHOO] each dateList:2014.04.21 2014.04.22 2014.04.23 2014.04.24 2014.04.25; 

Now that the hdb has been created, you can load it from disk and query with qSQL

q)\l .

q)select from outputTbl where date = 2014.04.24, sym = `GOOG

date       sym  time                          src price size
------------------------------------------------------------
2014.04.24 GOOG 2014.04.24D13:53:59.182000000 O   46.43 2453
```